# xcodebuild build failed with Xcode 7.1 and iOS 9.1 for iOS project with Cordova

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ios9.1, xcode7.1

I am trying to build iOS projects from the command line as part of a CI system. I intend to use the **xcodebuild** command to get an app file, then the app file will be provided to the **xcrun** command to get a signed ipa file for distribution.

My projects use **Cordova**, which is located in the folder `<project-folder>/CordovaLib`.

In the project folder, I executed the following command from within an Ant script:

```
xcodebuild -target "<project-name>" -configuration Release clean build
```

The CordovaLib target was built succesfully, and it was produced the file:

`<project-folder>/CordovaLib/build/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a`

This is visible by the following snippet of log:

> [exec] CreateUniversalBinary build/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a
>   normal armv7\ armv7s\ arm64 [exec]     cd `<project-folder>`/CordovaLib
>   [exec]     export
>   PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/quake/bin:Applications/tools/apache-ant-1.8.4/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin"
>
> [exec]/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool
>   -static `<project-folder>`/CordovaLib/build/CordovaLib.build/Release-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/libCordova.a
>   `<project-folder>`/CordovaLib/build/CordovaLib.build/Release-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/libCordova.a
>   `<project-folder>`/CordovaLib/build/CordovaLib.build/Release-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Objects-normal/arm64/libCordova.a
>   -o `<project-folder>`/CordovaLib/build/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a

During the build of the target `<project-name>` I got the following error for three times:

> ld: file not found:
>   /build/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a clang: error:
>   linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

And finally:

> The following build commands failed:  Ld
>   build/HelloWorldProjectHelloWorldIpad.build/Release-iphoneos/HelloWorldProjectHelloWorldIpad.build/Objects-normal/armv7/HelloWorld
>   normal armv7  Ld
>   build/HelloWorldProjectHelloWorldIpad.build/Release-iphoneos/HelloWorldProjectHelloWorldIpad.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/HelloWorld
>   normal armv7s     Ld
>   build/HelloWorldProjectHelloWorldIpad.build/Release-iphoneos/HelloWorldProjectHelloWorldIpad.build/Objects-normal/arm64/HelloWorld
>   normal arm64 (3 failures)

So the file `libCordova.a` was produced in the folder:

`<project-folder>/CordovaLib/build/Release-iphoneos`

and it was searched instead in:

`<project-folder>/build/Release-iphoneos`

I'm using Xcode Version 7.1 (7B91b) with iOS 9.1.

Should I set something on Xcode in addition to the parameters I have used in the `xcodebuild` command from the command line?

Thanks in advance, Simone.

Comment: cordova has commands to build the apps, why don't you use them instead?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however I'm required to use Xcode command line tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My project comes from a MEAP IDE. I discovered that the auto-generated project file `project.pbxproj` had this setting for the linker:

OTHER_LDFLAGS=-force_load "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libCordova.a" -Obj-C

Hence I modified this way the xcodebuild command invocation:

```
xcodebuild -target "<project-name>" -configuration Release clean build 'OTHER_LDFLAGS=-force_load "$SRCROOT/CordovaLib/build/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a" -Obj-C'
```

That resolved my problem.

Comment: Whats about this error : Ld /Users/confiz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CloudMessage-afevkkqtjcnmoddycvosdhbgoraa/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/LTDMessaging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/CloudMessage.build/Release-iphoneos/LTDMessaging.build/Objects-normal/arm64/LTD\ Messaging normal arm64